# Principal is null in controller when using http.csrf().disable()

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a controller and POJO that I want to test. The `GET` to the REST interface forces a login and returns a principal object and so all is good. I was able to extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to enable and username and password for testing.

However, during testing, the Spring framework requires a CSRF token for a `POST` request. Since I have no UI and I am only testing the REST interface I want to disable it temporarily.

So I extended `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` as per the documentation:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("{noop}password").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();    
    }
}
```

However this disabled the authentication. My controller receives a `Principal` object that is `null`. Here is my controller:

```java
import java.security.Principal;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.neutech.model.ShoppingCart;

@Scope("session")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cart/api/v1")
public class SomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/thing", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void create(@RequestBody String stuff,@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal user) {

         // do stuff
}
```

I have tried various flavours of setting CSRF for specific URLs or HTTP verbs. All with the same result. The principal delivered to the controller is `null`.

After scouring the net for some kind of resolution to this I can come up with nothing. There are lots of examples tell me to do exactly what I am doing. However I only find only other similar type questions.

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to enable authentication change your configure method, try this:

```
       http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .fullyAuthenticated();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring Boot 1.5, you could disable CSRF by properties, see 
[Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties):

> ```
> security.enable-csrf=false # Enable Cross Site Request Forgery support.
> ```

If you use Spring Boot 2.0, you have to write a complete Spring Security configuration, see [Spring Boot Security 2.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Security-2.0#custom-security):

> **Custom Security**
>
> If you want to configure custom security for your application, you will need to add a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` that adds all the bits that you want to configure. In order to avoid ordering issues with the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, Spring Boot auto-configuration will back off completely.

Example:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable()
    }
}
```